# FloatField returns str object instead of Float in Django

Tags: python, django

While working on something in Django, I stumbled upon this wierd error (cuz it never happened before). If in a `FloatField` I saved a float value as string i.e. '245.4' instead of actual float value i.e. 245.4, then on accessing the value it returns back the string instead of float! the reason why abs(modelname.floatfield) threw `TypeError` today.

On research found this old thread in Django's forum (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19565). Is it decided and implemented yet or should I typecast values manually from now on or anyone has a better solution?

Comment: This is logical, since you here basically just set the attribute of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, and was a design decision, as is written in [ticket #12401](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12401#comment:10):

> Model attributes are **not converted to the correct Python types** when you set the attribute. That's the design decision we made, and one that isn't going to change without a lot of backwards incompatibilities.

This is thus expected behavior for (almost) all `Field`s, although one can, strictly speaking use the [`__get__` and `__set__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) methods to change that behavior (or use other techniques like metaclasses), so strictly speaking it *is* possible to add such behavior.

After all, you just set an attribute of a Python object, and that object happens to be a Python object. It is only when writing to the database, etc. that these attributes are converted to their corresponding database type and vice versa. In some scenario's that means if you store a value of one type in an object, if you store it in the database, and later retrieve the same object, that attribute has another type.

It however makes sense not to perform such conversions since, like the comment [ticket #12401](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12401#comment:10) mentions:

> In general, I expect to the following to pass, no matter what `foo`
>   is:
>
> ```
> >>> x = '2011-06-06'
> >>> foo.bar = x
> >>> assert foo.bar == x
> ```
>
> The proposed behaviour, though potentially useful or even better for
>   Django model objects, would certainly **violate that expectation**, so
>   the design decision we've made is certainly sensible.

Comment: It seems I would have to go for manual typecasting for the time being. Thanks for the explanation though. :)